# Too long string variable for axis in primefaces bar chart

Tags: html, css, primefaces, jqplot

I am trying to draw a barchart using primefaces. My problem is variables in the x-axis could be too long. I want to show say 100px long and if it is longer than that, it should show full length in a box, when mouse is over on it. I have tried to do it with css, but didn't work. Here is my jquery.jqplot.css:

```
.jqplot-xaxis-tick {
    width: 100px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

and in html I have this:

```
<p:barChart id="myChart" styleClass=".jqplot-xaxis-tick" value="#{indexBean.myChart}" />
```

With these, in the barchart it fits the string in 100px but by making it smaller so that it can't be even read.
Any help?